# how to update parse Object synchronized in cloud code then check if it was successfull?

Tags: javascript, synchronization, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

i want synchronized update parse object in cloud code and check if update was successfull?then run some logic and return result ot user.
parse use node SDK in parse cloud code and its examples are asynchronized.

[here](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#updating-objects) is parse doc example but async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use async/await:

```js
Parse.Cloud.define('myFunction', async req => {
  const GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
  const gameScore = new GameScore();

  gameScore.set("score", 1337);
  gameScore.set("playerName", "Sean Plott");
  gameScore.set("cheatMode", false);
  gameScore.set("skills", ["pwnage", "flying"]);

  await gameScore.save();

  // Now let's update it with some new data. In this case, only cheatMode and score
  // will get sent to the cloud. playerName hasn't changed.
  gameScore.set("cheatMode", true);
  gameScore.set("score", 1338);

  await gameScore.save();
});
```

Comment: then how can i check if update was successfull or not?or parse return error to client SDK(with considering we are on cloud code)when update fail and function return from fail point?

Comment: Yes. `await gameScore.save();` will throw an exception that will make the cloud code function to fail and consequently the SDK to receive the error message.